# How the followers of different Vaishnava sampradayas consider the stories of Vishnu tricking Tulasi and Vrinda?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, gaudiya-vaishnavism, ramanandi

How do Vaishnavas explain these stories of Vishnu tricking Vrinda and Tulasi. I am not asking how the act is justified, rather the beliefs of Vaishnavas regarding these stories(ie whether they consider them as interpolations with proofs or any deep meanings).

Comment: 'I am not asking how the act is justified rather the beliefs' - justifying the act is also a part of the belief.

Comment: @sv. Ofcourse, My question is whether they believe in the it's authenticity or else they don't and to provide inner meaning if possible. I have seen many vaishnavas especially of sri sampradayam to explain inner meanings of some incidents which I personally like. (whether the incident is authentic or not )it is justified in my view for some reasons. So I excluded that part in my question.